# Why do the data and code segments completely overlap in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, x86

Context: I'm reading "Understanding the Linux kernel, 3d ed", which uses the 2.6.11 kernel.

Question: As I understand, the physical address is obtained by translating the linear address, which is obtained by translating the logical address. The logical address consists of a segment selector, which identifies a segment in a Description Table

The Linux Global Description Table includes, amongst other segments, a user code and data segment. But the base address of both segments is `0x0`, and their size is also the same. So they completely overlap. So as I understand, the logical address `cs + offset` is identical to the logical address `ds + offset`, where `cs` and `ds` are the CPU registers that hold respectively the code segment selector and data segment selector. I think this is the case because both segments have the same base address, which is incremented with the offset to get the linear address.

If this is the case, and they both map to the same linear address, don't they also map to the same physical address? If so, what is the use of having separate `cs` and `ds` registers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The segmentation registers are a legacy from the early days of the x86 processors, when the `offset` wasn't large enough to address all of the memory the processor could address.  The original [8086](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086) had a 20-bit address space, but could only use a 16-bit offset.  You had to use the segment registers to specify which 64KB of the 1024KB address space you wanted.  The segment registers were effectively 20-bit registers where the lowest 4 bits were forced to 0.  Loading a segment register set the upper 16 bits of the register.  This allowed `segment + offset` to cover the entire 20-bit address space.

The segment registers still exist, but Linux sets them to 0 so it can pretend they don't.  Modern x86 processors (meaning the [80386](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80386) and newer) can use an offset big enough to cover all their address space, making memory segmentation a complication that's no longer necessary.  Read [x86 memory segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) and the [flat memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_memory_model) for more details.

Comment: so linux only uses paging and no segmentation in its memory management?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Actually we have sort of a return to segment-like model with PAE, where 64G (36 bit) address space can only be addressed in 4G chunks by the application.

Comment: @cjm May I extend this question. When 20bit physical address was obtained by adding (16bit segment << 4) and 16bit offset, doesn't that mean , that one physical address can be obtained from multiple different pairs of segment and offset i.e. segments overlap? For example... 1010 + 0011 = 101011 and 1000 + 1011 = 101011

Comment: @LukášŘádek, yes, that's true, and I'm sure there was software that did that for various reasons.  The segmentation registers weren't really about memory protection, but just about expanding the address space.

Comment: @cjm, thank you... in the meantime I have read a nice article about it http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html , from which I understood, that the overlapping is basically a byproduct from being able to start new segment as close to the previous one's end as possible